# How to log in to ssh without public key? Only with username and password

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to know if in google cloud it is possible to log in to my ssh server without publickey, since I need to delete and create users frequently and it becomes annoying to have to generate the keys

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Head over to the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config, and change the following line :

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Then restart sshd :

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Comment: and what password it will use? the same of console?

Comment: can i enable pubkey, password auth both

Comment: yes, you can look at this post : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231314/how-do-i-configure-sshd-to-1-require-public-key-and-2-require-a-password-for/231375#231375

Comment: This solution will keep pubkey authentication enabled as well. If you have a key, it will use that for login, otherwise ask you for a password. (The [other linked question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/231375) is for requiring both at the same time, for one login.)